# Android Sync Adapter remove add account function from Applications & sync options screen

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

When I created my application using a sync adapter, I noticed that you can add an account in the "Applications & Sync" menu in Settings. I want my application to have only one account per device, so is there a way to remove my application from that list?

Answer (score 2):

When you define your sync-adapter you can specify that it is not visible to the user by adding `android:userVisible="false"` to your XML file - this will exclude it from the settings page.

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.mycompany.account"
    android:userVisible="false"/>
```

Comment: That's seriously odd. Even if you remove the application manually, restart the device (or even better, factory reset) and reinstall the app with userVisible=false?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix this? Even if I remove `android:label` and `android:icon` from the `account-authenticator`, I get an empty row in the "Add an account" list.